# Adding a title to my SVG window erases one datapoint? (d3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset of 100 numbers, and within an SVG I create a bunch of text objects to display those numbers using the code below:

```
          svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                console.log(output_format(d));
                return output_format(d);
```

This works perfectly.  However, if I try to create a title later on (outside of my d3.csv brackets) with this code:

```
        svg.append("text")
          .text("Actual Labels")
          .attr("x", w/1.92)
          .attr("y", top_gap/1.5)
          .attr("class", "title");
```

Then the first datapoint gets erased, and does not even display in console.log(output_format(d));.  What is happening here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your single text element is appended first because the other code has to wait for the AJAX request. So when you're appending the remainder of your text elements, one is already there. This existing text element is selected by `selectAll("text")` and then matched with the data in `dataset`. By default, d3 matches data based on the index -- the first element in the array matches the first element that is already there and is therefore not in the `.enter()` selection which you operate on.

The easiest way to fix this is to give the text labels that you append dynamically a different class and select based on that. That is, your code for appending the dynamic labels would look like

```
svg.selectAll("text.label")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("class", "label")
       .text(function(d) {
            console.log(output_format(d));
            return output_format(d);
       });
```

No other changes should be required.

Comment: Lars, thanks again.  I appreciate the clear explanation as well.